# Where to place setScrollsToTop for custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uitextview

I have a UITableView that has two custom cells.  I have subclassed UITableViewCell for each of the cells.  In both, I have a UITextView that can scroll.  I want the user to be able to tap the top bar to scroll to the top.  I know that I need to turn off scrollsToTop for the text views.  But I don't know exactly where to place it.  I have tried inside the custom cell like this.

```
#import "MessageCell.h"

@implementation MessageCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    [_messageText setScrollsToTop:NO];

}
return self;
}

@end
```

But that did not work.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I can't figure out where else to put it.  I tried in the actual tableview vc, but it did not recognize my property.  Thanks in advance for any and all help!!

To go along with my response below.  I have a cell that I call in cellForRowAtIndexPath called FaceBookCell.  This cell contains a UIImageView.  I subclasses that into a message cell and photocell.  They both need the UIImageView, but message cell shows a message in a UITextView and Photocell shows a message in UITextView and a photo in another UIImageVIew.  I need to let Facebook cell know to stop scrollsToTop for the other cells.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alloc init the text view also
Try calling the method from:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
....
[cell stopScrollToTop];

.....
return cell;
}
```

////In cell

```
#import "MessageCell.h"

@implementation MessageCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    _messageText = [[UITextView alloc]init];

}
return self;
}

-(void)stopScrollToTop{
   [_messageText setScrollsToTop:NO];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for the input. However, each of my custom cells happen to be a subclass of another cell that I call in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so the cell does not see the stopScrollToTop method.  So I need to somehow get the cell I call to see the stopScrollToTop method.  Any ideas?  And thanks again for the help.

Comment: Why not use views instead of a subclass cell within a cell? I don't think a cell within a cell is the best approach? Maybe view in the cell. Then in the view, do whatever you want

Comment: thanks for the idea.  It worked like a charm.  Wish I would have thought of that earlier!